# Get Metadata from Open Office Files

Tags: java, apache-tika, odf, odftoolkit

I need to modify only the Open Office file metadata. How I can do it without loading the entire file into memory (file.odt)?
I need to work only with the file: meta.xml and label:  ... metadata ...

I'm using Apache ODF Toolkit 0.5-incubating. My code loads the meta.xml file but I can not get metadata:

```
OdfPackage pkg = OdfPackage.loadPackage(new File("file.odt"));
Node d = pkg.getDom("meta.xml").getElementsByTagName("office:document-meta").item(0);

for(int i =0; i<d.getAttributes().getLength();i++) {
  String nombre = d.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName();
  String valor = d.getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue();
  System.out.println("Clave: " + nombre + " valor: " + valor);
}
```

Comment: Which do you want - Open Office format (OOXML), or Open Document Format (ODF)? Only you mention both in your question!

Comment: I'm working with Open Document Format files (*. odt, *. ods, *. odp). The only tool I've seen to work with them is Apache ODF Toolkit

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work with a range of file formats, the [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) is your best bet. Tika provides a common interface for extracting text and metadata from a large number of formats, and hides the complexity of the different types and formats from you.

On the command line, to extract the metadata from [this sample file](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/repository/source/test-resources/quick/quick.odt) you'd do

```
java -jar tika-app-1.4.jar --metadata quick.odt
```

And you'd get back a huge amount of metadata:

```
Author: Jesper Steen Møller
Character Count: 43
Content-Length: 7042
Content-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
Creation-Date: 2005-09-06T23:34:00
Edit-Time: PT2M0S
Image-Count: 0
Keywords: Pangram, fox, dog
Last-Modified: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
Last-Save-Date: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
Object-Count: 0
Page-Count: 1
Paragraph-Count: 1
Table-Count: 0
Word-Count: 9
cp:subject: Gym class featuring a brown fox and lazy dog
creator: Jesper Steen Møller
date: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
dc:creator: Jesper Steen Møller
dc:description: Gym class featuring a brown fox and lazy dog
dc:language: en-US
dc:subject: Pangram, fox, dog
dc:title: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
dcterms:created: 2005-09-06T23:34:00
dcterms:modified: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
description: Gym class featuring a brown fox and lazy dog
editing-cycles: 5
generator: OpenOffice.org/1.9.125$Win32 OpenOffice.org_project/680m125$Build-8947
initial-creator: Nevin Nollop
language: en-US
meta:author: Jesper Steen Møller
meta:character-count: 43
meta:creation-date: 2005-09-06T23:34:00
meta:image-count: 0
meta:initial-author: Nevin Nollop
meta:object-count: 0
meta:page-count: 1
meta:paragraph-count: 1
meta:save-date: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
meta:table-count: 0
meta:word-count: 9
modified: 2005-09-06T23:49:00
nbCharacter: 43
nbImg: 0
nbObject: 0
nbPage: 1
nbPara: 1
nbTab: 0
nbWord: 9
resourceName: quick.odt
subject: Gym class featuring a brown fox and lazy dog
title: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
xmpTPg:NPages: 1
```

From Java, you could get the same with something as simple as

```
TikaConfig tika = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(new File("test.ods"));

tika.getParser().parse(input, null, metadata, context);
```

And you'd get the metadata on the [Metadata object](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/api/org/apache/tika/metadata/Metadata.html)

Comment: It ´s possible to count number of sheets using Apache Tika for           "xls","xlsx", "ods","ots","xlsm" and  "sxc"?

Comment: @Goldbones I believe so, but ask a new question if for some reason it isn't working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OdfDocument Package provided by org.odftoolkit. You can get the dependency here => https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.odftoolkit/odfdom-java

You can parse your document

```
OdfDocument odfDocument = OdfDocument.loadDocument(new URL(URLPath).openStream());
```

And get metadata like for example

```
wordCount = odfDocument.getOfficeMetadata().getDocumentStatistic().getWordCount();
```